# How Do I Trigger A Post-Build Event In Visual Studio Community 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

I right-clicked on my C++ project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Build Events - Post-Build Event and set the command line to `calc`.

I now do `Build - Rebuild Solution` and although I get this in the Output pane Calculator never launches.

```
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I even tried Configuration Properties - Custom Build Step - General and set the command line to `notepad` and Execute After to `CoreBuild` but nothing happened on Rebuild Solution either.

NB: My Post-Build event is actually a copy command but since that isn't working I wanted to break it down to something simpler.

Comment: it should work, in vs2012 and vs2013 prof the first way works fine.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't though :( Is there an extra error log somewhere that might give more info to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inherited this project and it had several configurations in it (ANSI Debug/Release and Unicode Debug/Release).

Since I am only targeting Unicode I manually removed those sections from the sln and vcxproj files.

With this in mind, it then became clearer that Visual Studio was showing different options for different configurations.

After switching to the All Configurations options and deleting from the other sections I could make calc run.

xcopy still failed for a while as `$(TargetPath)` didn't resolve correctly when the `OuputFile` option had been changed in the Linker to suffix "_Debug" for the debug config.

It all seems to work now.